# How can I replace an std::string member with a non-heap limited-size string?

Tags: c++, string, stdstring, stack-allocation

I have a codebase with some ubiquitous data structure; and said structure has an std::string member. Now, for reasons, I want this codebase to work when std::string is unavailable, and in fact with no dynamic allocation of memory (at least not the usual way). I can also verify that that string member never has a string longer than M characters (and M is small).

Now, what should I replace std::string with, so that I don't have to do a lot of rewriting, on one hand; and that my constraints are satisfied on the other?

Note:

- I can't move the computation of the string to compile-time.
- It's ok if the solution only has a trivial constructor, a `const char*` constructor, or both.
- Solutions involving the use of `std::string_view` may be relevant (but I'm not sure whether that would be useful).

Comment: Sounds like you just want a `std::array<char, M + 1>`. You can wrap it in a class if you want to keep a `std::string`-like interface. Though beware that this change may make your type significantly less move friendly, less container friendly, and generally can significantly increase it's size.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Given that *"M is small"* and `std::string` is a largeish type (24..32 bytes), there might be no change, or even improvement in move friendliness and class size, depending on how small it is.

Comment: You may just need a new string allocator.

Comment: Boost has something called [`static_string`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/static_string/doc/html/index.html), with storage equivalent to an array, and an interface that strives to match `std::string`.

Comment: I also have a custom [small_string](https://github.com/Ambeco/mpd/blob/master/SmallContainers/small_string.hpp) which is apparently similar to boost `static_string`.

Answer (score 3):

`char[M + 1]` would probably be a decent, simple option to investigate. The amount of rewriting may be more or less depending on how you have used the string member so far.

If the "std::stringiness" of the member is used a lot, then you could possibly reduce the amount of rewrite by implementing a custom class that offers similar interface as `std::string`, but internally uses `char[M + 1]`. `boost::static_string` mentioned by [Drew Dormann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68038684/how-can-i-replace-an-stdstring-with-a-non-heap-limited-size-string/68038768#comment120256589_68038684) is a template for such class.

P.S. If you can still use `std::string` and are only restricted from using dynamic memory, then you could potentially keep using `std::string` with a custom allocator instead, as mentioned by [Galik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68038684/how-can-i-replace-an-stdstring-with-a-non-heap-limited-size-string/68038768#comment120256538_68038684).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid "rolling my own" string-like class. `boost::static_string` could be relevant, but is perhaps a bit overkill, since its templated on a bunch of stuff; and I would need to either drag in all of boost, or rip it out of Boost. Might still do it.

Comment: @einpoklum: "The library is usable in two different modes: standalone and Boost dependent. This library defaults to Boost dependent mode; standalone mode is opt-in through the use of a configuration macro." https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/static_string/doc/html/index.html  `BOOST_STATIC_STRING_STANDALONE`

Answer (score 0):

A minimum-hassle potential solution could utilize the specifics of your case, sacrificing generality for simplicity:

You wrote the string you want to replace is actually a member of another struct. This already allows using an array member of the struct, as @eerorika suggests, without worrying about array decay. But - arrays don't the interface of an std::string.

You said you didn't see how an `std::string_view` would be useful - and that's because there's no storage to go with it.

Well, combine the two! ... no, don't write a new class with both storage and a string interface. Rather, add a `char [M+1]` field to your struct, with a new field name, and use the original field name for a string_view looking at the array (with the appropriate length of course)!

This complicates construction and assignment a bit - i.e. it's no longer trivial member-wise construction - but you will then be able to pass this object around and use the same field as before like an std::string.

```
  struct ubiquitous {
     // other members
     char[M+1] string_data;
     std::string_view original_field;

     // apply rule of 5: ctor, move ctor, assignment, move assignment
     // and a trivial dtor (at least for your two fields)
     // ... so, a "rule of 4" in this case
  };
```

If you don't have a `string_view` available, i.e. it's pre-C++17 code, then you can get [Martin Moene's back-ported string_view](https://github.com/martinmoene/string-view-lite) (GitHub).